# How to dispatch action 'toggleSelect' on a sunburst chart instead of a pie chart with echarts?

Tags: angular, charts, echarts, sunburst-diagram

I want to dispatch the action 'toggleSelect' for my sunburst chart, but it's not working. It works only with pie charts. Is it possible to active the toggle on a sunburst chart programmatically with echarts?

Echarts version: 5.3.3
Angular version: 14

That's how I am trying to do it

`this.chart.dispatchAction({type: 'toggleSelect', seriesIndex: 0, name: labelName});`

Comment: Hi, please, share some lines of code. 
How are you trying to do? What's your Angular version ? What's your charts library version ?

Comment: I just edited my post according to your comment, thank you!